# Send Confirmation Mail from Flask App that is hosted on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, flask-mail, confirmation-email

flask app is sending confirmation mail perfectly and it is working fine when I run the app on "localhost" and the confirmation URL also working, but after I deployed the app on amazon ec2 instance it not sending the confirmation mail.

Comment: What do you mean by not sending confirmation mail. Any error? Paste it in question? you need to include the code which sends email and configuration of flask mail. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mail port is open from the security groups.

Comment: thank you , i added the port to security groups but still not getting the mail